# Difference between generic method and non-generic method

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between these two methods?

```
public <T extends Serializable, Y extends List<T>> void foo(Y y, T t);
```

and

```
public void foo(Serializable ser, List<Serializable> list);
```

Comment: The first one is typed. Hence, you will not need to cast its result. For example, `Y y2 = foo(y1, t1); ` would not work with the second example. You would have to do  `Y y2 = (Y) foo(y1, t1); `

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Methods are `void`.

Comment: It allows you use the same base class / method for managing multiple objects. A good example is the Java built-in interface `List<T>` which you are using in your example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes; did not see that. hence, my comment would be only applicable if the method returned a T or Y.

Comment: The example is not totally correct, because in the first method there is `List<T>` instead of `List<Serializable>`.

Comment: the first one is equivalent to `public <T extends Serializable> void foo(List<T> y, T t);`. The `Y` is unnecessary because it is only used once as a parameter type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public <T extends Serializable, Y extends List<T>> void foo(Y y, T t);
```

The generics in this function force you specify *exactly* what type `T` is, and it must be *exactly* the same in both parameters. A sub-class of `T` is not allowed, it must be ***that*** type. The compiler will not allow otherwise.

```
public void foo(Serializable ser, List<Serializable> list);
```

In this non-generic function, there is no relation between the types of the parameters, other than they are both `Serializable`. This allows `ser` to be ***any*** type of `Serializable`, and the elements in `list` to be ***any*** type of `Serializable`. They may be the same type, they may not. It doesn't matter to the compiler.

A bit more information for any newbies that might be reading this:

Generics only exist in source code. They do not exist once the code is compiled. This is called "type erasure":

https://www.google.com/search?q=type+erasure+java

This erasure is done so pre-generics code can interoperate with generics code. So code that existed before generics was introduced would not *have* to be changed. New code is encouraged to always use generics.

Answer (score 5):

The first one can be called with a `List<String>` (for example) as argument. The second one can't, because a `List<String>` is not a `List<Serializable>`.

The second one can be called with an `Integer` as first argument, and a `List<Serializable>` as second argument. The first one, however, will only accept a `List<Integer>` as argument if the other argument is an `Integer`.